# if statement gone wrong

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

im trying to use a if statement to print if the led is on but the ide is ignoring the if statement and only doing whats outside it also ive tried  using the gpiozero library but it reads the pins wrong i dont have any jumpers connected to pin 17 but its the only pin that turns the led on

```
from rpi.gpiozero import LED
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)

for i in range(25):
    GPIO.OUTPUT(11,True)
    if GPIO.OUTPUT(11,True):
        print('LED is on')
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.OUTPUT(11,False)
    if GPIO.OUTPUT(11,False):
        print('LED is off')
    time.sleep(1)
GPIO.CLEANUP()
```

Comment: What is the return value of `GPIO.OUTPUT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **setting** the GPIO Pin in your `if` statement. You need to **read** it.

`GPIO.Input` Returns 0 if OFF or 1 if ON

So your code should look like this:

```
if GPIO.input(11):
    print('LED is on')
```

You can read about the usage in the [docs](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/) under "Input".